# Excel / VBA_ Rename Table headers based on cells on separate sheet (same workbook)

Tags: excel, vba

I have a Table requiring 14 column names ( Sheet 3) to be renamed based on text values in 14 cells (sheet one shown on a separate sheet (same workbook) the cells in sheet 1 are pick lists.
Any assistance on this would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

- Update table header with `HeaderRowRange`

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub UpdateTableHeader()
    If Sheets("Sheet3").ListObjects.Count > 0 Then
        Sheets("Sheet3").ListObjects(1).HeaderRowRange.Value = _
            Application.Transpose(Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A14").Value)
    End If
End Sub
```

[image]

*Microsoft documentation:*

> [ListObject.HeaderRowRange property (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.listobject.headerrowrange?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbaxl10.chm734084)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue)